# Spring how to use non embbed database

Tags: spring

I learned from this article https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/. And I have a problem because every time the application is turned off and turn it again, the data from the database are lost and must be entered again. How do data to be stored permanently?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is lost because the tutorial uses an in-memory database. For the data to be persisted, you need to use a database like MySQL or Postgres. The following steps would alter the tutorial to use MySQL:

1. Replace the dependency on H2 with MySQL. I.e., if you are using maven, in pom.xml, replace

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.m2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Put MySQL connection info in `src/main/resources/application.properties`, like this:

   ```
   spring.jpa.database: MYSQL
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update

   spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db-name
   spring.datasource.username: your db-username e.g. root
   spring.datasource.password: db-password
   ```
3. Install MySQL if you haven't already, and create the database.